# Can I use Python to develop extensions for all major browsers?

Tags: python, browser

Can I use **Python** to develop extensions for all major browsers?

If not then what languages will I need to know to develop extensions for:

- Chrome
- Firefox
- Safari
- IE
- Opera

Comment: Can you use it to develop extensions for _any_ major browsers? I dont think so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most extensions are just bundled HTML, CSS, JS and image files, plus some metadata. You'll need to be good at JS, and most importantly, you'll also need to learn about each browser's API.

Here are documentation and "getting started" pages for extensions development on different browsers:

- [Chrome](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/overview.html)
- [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Building_an_Extension) (see also [XUL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XUL))
- [Safari](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)
- [Opera](http://www.opera.com/docs/pluginapi/)
- [Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753587%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

IE also supports COM's and languages targeting the CLR (eg: C#).

Comment: Nein, ich bin Brasilianer, aber ich spreche ein bisschen Deutsch ;-)

Comment: Ah, just like my stepmom ^^ btw, saw that Jawohl! :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can but you will need to compile your code to js using rapydscript for further reading visit https://pythonspot.com/create-a-chrome-plugin-with-python/