# Is it possible to make a cross browser extension linked to a Python web app backend?

Tags: javascript, python, browser, cross-browser

### Current Situation

I am in the early phases of designing a web app that the user will interact with via a browser extension that will be in the form of a horizontal nav bar. I wanted to use Pylons and Python on this project but am unsure how it fits in. As I understand it a browser extension is "[just bundled HTML, CSS, JS and image files, plus some metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836262/can-i-use-python-to-develop-extensions-for-all-major-browsers)".

***But what does that mean?***

> Does that mean that HTML, CSS, JS,
>   image files and meta data are used to
>   create **just** the front end GUI nav
>   bar part of the browser extension?

Or

> Does that mean that HTML, CSS, JS and
>   image files make up the front end GUI
>   nav bar and JS and meta data will take
>   care of the back end logic?

I ask this because I know that one can program web apps in Java Script alone.

### Conclusion

Ideally I would like Python/Pylons to be the main brain of the web app and do the heavy lifting in terms of logic. Python/Pylons would basically take in data via JavaScript and give back data to Java Script/AJAX which would then, in real-time, update the GUI nav bar.

***Is this possible?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the extension uses HTTP to communicate, you can use whatever server-side technology you like to generate the data passed back to the client.

Comment: Wow that is simple. So I guess no JS is needed at all then?

Comment: Not beyond what your extension will be using to actually run.

Comment: So technically I could just make the extension only in HTML and CSS then, right?

Comment: If the only point of the HTML is to hold links that load other HTML documents, sure.